# Close in app browser after a redirect

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have an ad partner that is redirecting users to the app store after an ad in our app is tapped. We load an in-app browser which does the redirect. Nothing in the browser ever loads, it is just a white screen. Once the user returns to our app they are looking at that empty browser. Is there anyway to dismiss or close that browser once the redirect is completed?

We don't have any control over the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by skipping the in-app browser and used Safari instead. App store re-directs are happening without showing the browser window and all the other ads are working as expected.

Plus I got to delete a bunch of old code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of in-app browser you are using in your app? Like a library or an `UIWebView`? If it's an `UIWebView`, there's a callback method when the webpage is loaded (and probably, redirected the link):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

If you're using a library, I'm pretty sure it also has a method like that.

Comment: Thank you but this wasn't necessary. I am using Safari now and it is working as desired.